# systemd share cifs "mount error(13): Permission denied"

Tags: linux, debian, systemd, cifs

I want to mount share with `/etc/systemd/system`
File : `mnt-win7_docs.mount`

Content :

```
[Unit]
Description=Mount docs

[Mount]
What=//192.168.1.5/docs/
Where=/mnt/win7_docs/
Type=cifs
Options=user,username=<user>,password='<passwd>',iocharset=utf8

[Install]
WantedBy = multi-user.target
```

When I try `systemctl start mnt-win7_docs.mount`

I have the following error :

```
mnt-win7_docs.mount - Mount docs
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/mnt-win7_docs.mount; enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since mar. 2016-09-06 14:59:00 CEST; 2s ago
    Where: /mnt/win7_docs
     What: //192.168.1.5/docs/
  Process: 36306 ExecMount=/bin/mount -n //192.168.1.5/docs/ /mnt/win7_docs -t cifs -o user,username=<user>,password='<passwd>',iocharset=utf8 (code=exited, status=32)

sept. 06 14:59:00 dtools mount[36306]: mount error(13): Permission denied
sept. 06 14:59:00 dtools mount[36306]: Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)
sept. 06 14:59:00 dtools systemd[1]: mnt-win7_docs.mount mount process exited, code=exited status=32
sept. 06 14:59:00 dtools systemd[1]: Failed to mount Mount docs
sept. 06 14:59:00 dtools systemd[1]: Unit mnt-win7_docs.mount entered failed state.
```

But when I try : `/bin/mount -n //192.168.1.5/docs/ /mnt/win7_docs -t cifs -o user,username=<user>,password='<passwd>',iocharset=utf8`.
It's ok ...

Do you have some ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, it's works.
The problem should come from special characters in the password.

Now I have :

```
[Unit]
Description=Mount docs

[Mount]
What=//192.168.1.5/docs/
Where=/mnt/win7_docs/
Type=cifs
Options=user,credentials=/root/.credentials,iocharset=utf8

[Install]
WantedBy = multi-user.target
```

/root/.credentials

```
username=<user>
password=<password>
```

So, password without simple quote.